# Add cordova plugin from GitLab private repo

Tags: git, cordova, ionic-framework, gitlab, cordova-plugins

```
cordova plugin add http://gitlab.com/<user>/<private-repo>.git
```

I am unable to add a cordova plugin from a private repo in GitLab. When I run the above command it throws me the following error:

```
Error: Failed to fetch plugin http://gitlab.com/<user>/<private-repo>.git via registry.
    Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
    Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
    Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    npm ERR! fetch failed http://gitlab.com/<user>/<private-repo>.git
    npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 401
    npm ERR! fetch failed http://gitlab.com/<user>/<private-repo>.git
    npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 401
    npm ERR! fetch failed http://gitlab.com/<user>/<private-repo>.git
    npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
    npm ERR! argv "~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/node" 
    "~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/npm" "install" 
    "http://gitlab.com/<user>/<private-repo>.git" "--save"
    npm ERR! node v6.4.0
    npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3

    npm ERR! fetch failed with status code 401
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
    npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

**Note**: I am using cordova 7.0.1

I can see that status code is 401. I was accepting a password prompt for fetching from the private repo but unfortunately thats not the case. 
[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313178/cordova-plugin-from-private-github-repository) was asked but I don't want to clone the repo and add via local folder. Any kind of help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 10):

Try the following to add a plugin from a private GitLab repository using the latest version of Cordova.

```
cordova plugin add git+ssh://git@gitlab.example.com:<group|user>/<repo>#<branch>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the `--no-fetch` work-around is... that the plugin is not fetched.

There are related open issues referenced in Cordova issue tracker for versions 7.x and 8.x:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13507
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12756

I found two work-around:

- clone the repo and add the plugin referring to the local path (see [comment in CB-13507](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13507?focusedCommentId=16342997&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16342997))
- downgrade to Cordova v6.x to add your plugin then rollback to latest version

Answer (score 1):

you need to no-fetch this plugin. So, you need to run that command:

```
sudo cordova plugin add http://gitlab.com/<user>/<private-repo>.git --save --nofetch
```

Regards

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work. Thanks for answering.